# Error propagation log2

Tags: experimental-physics, error-analysis

I have a quick question to report some numbers on an experiment. I made measurements of fluorescence in a titration of a chemical. The titrations were 1:2 serial dilutions so I report each fluorescence as a function of the log2 concentration:

concentration chemical x: 1 , 0.5, 0.25 
reported concentration chemical x (log2): 0, -1,-2
fluorescence measurement: 5, 10, 25

I’m interested in reporting the concentrations of a chemical that lead to a specific fluorescence. So, let’s say I want to report when the fluorescence reaches 10, in this case that would be -1.

So keeping that in mind: When I make error propagation calculations should I use the log2 or the linear measurements?

Sometimes I need to interpolate to get the reported concentrations. For instance, when I want to get the concentration that leads to fluorescence 15. Does that change anything for the calculations?